# Per-row index of a matrix in R (including 0-rows)

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Assume we have the following logical matrix in R:

```
A <- matrix(as.logical(c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)), nrow=4)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I want to convert this matrix into a column-wise index using

```
B <- column_wise_index(A)
```

where `column_wise_index` returns a vector containing the same number of elements as the number of rows in `A` (4), and each element contains the column of `A` that has a logical value `TRUE`. For `A` above, `B` should resemble

```
B <- c(3,2,0,1)
# [1] 3 2 0 1
```

where `0` indicates a row that has no `TRUE` value.

---

The closest I've come is `apply`ing `which` by row:

```
unlist(apply(A, 1, function(x) which(x)))
# [1] 3 2 1
```

However, the result skips `0`, and I'm not sure how efficient this is for large matrices (say ~100K x 100 entries).

Comment: maybe `max.col(A) - (rowSums(A) == 0)` havent checked on a large matrix

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that is more in the spirit of how you started, but you have to admire @rawr's clever solution.

```
A <- matrix(as.logical(c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)), nrow=4)

TrueSpots = apply(A, 1, which)
TrueSpots[!sapply(TrueSpots, length)] = 0
unlist(TrueSpots)
[1] 3 2 0 1
```

Update including @akrun's suggestion:

```
TrueSpots = apply(A, 1, which)
TrueSpots[!lengths(TrueSpots)] = 0
unlist(TrueSpots)
[1] 3 2 0 1
```

Comment: You may use the faster `lengths` instead of `sapply(.., length)`

Answer (score 1):

`max.col(A)` identifies the index where the maximum entry occurs within the *row*. Ties are broken at random (by default). `rowSums(A)` on a logical matrix performs a per-row binary addition.

Based on the assumption that each row has at most one `TRUE` value, `rowSums(A)` will result in a binary vector. Performing a vector-based multiplication nullifies the truly `FALSE` rows in A.

```
> A <- matrix(as.logical(c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)), nrow=4)
> max.col(A)*rowSums(A)
[1] 3 2 0 1
```